# Thread safe switching of Linked-List nodes without locking the entire list

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, starvation

I'm learning about threads, locks etc. Therefore, I don't want to use `synchronized` key word or any class that is `thread-safe` other then `semaphore` and `ReentrantLock` (without Atomic variables).

I want to have kind of synchronized `LinkedList<T>` of `Node<T>`, order by the size of `T` (assume that `T` is `implements` an `interface` that have `size` and `increment` functions and `lock`, `unlock` functions). I want to be able to replace two `Nodes` by their `T.getSize()` function without locking all the list.

For example, if I only had one thread the function will be a "classic" replace function, something like that:

```
public void IncrementAndcheckReplace(Node<T> node)
{
    node.getData().incrementSize();
    Node nextNode = node.getNext();
    if(nextNode == null)
        return;
    while(node.getData().getSize() > nextNode.getData().getSize())
     {
        node.getPrev().setNext(nextNode);
        nextNode.setPrev(node.getPrev());
        Node nextnext = nextNode.getNext();
        nextNode.setNext(node);
        node.setPrev(nextNode);
        node.setNext(nextnext);
        nextnext.setPrev(node);

        nextNode = node.getNext();
        if(nextNode == null)
            break; 
    }

}
```

now lets get to the synchronized problem.

I thought about trying to do something like that to create a `lock` for my `Nodes`:

```
public void IncrementAndcheckReplace(Node<T> node)
{
    node.lock(); //using fair ReentrantLock for specific node       
    node.getData().incrementSize();
    Node nextNode = node.getNext();
    if(nextNode == null)
    {
        node.unlock();
        return;
    }
    nextNode.lock();
    while(node.getData().getSize() > nextNode.getData().getSize())
     {
        Node prev = node.getPrev();
        if(prev != null)
        {
            prev.lock();
            prev.setNext(nextNode);
        }
        nextNode.setPrev(prev);
        Node nextnext = nextNode.getNext();
        if(nextnext != null)
        {
            nextnext.lock();
            nextnext.setPrev(node);
        }
        nextNode.setNext(node);
        node.setPrev(nextNode);
        node.setNext(nextnext);
        if(prev!=null)
            prev.unlock();
        if(nextnext!=null)
            nextnext.unlock();
        nextNode.unlock();

        nextNode = node.getNext();
        if(nextNode == null)
            break;
        nextNode.lock();
    }
    node.unlock();
}
```

the problem is that this is not thread safe as all, and dead-lock may happens. For example lets assume that we have `Node a, Node b` which `a.next == b and b.prev==a` that now if thread A trying to use replace function on a, and thread B trying to use replace function on b, they will both be locked and I will get nowhere ever.

how can I make the replace function to be `thread safe` without `lock` the entire list? I want to avoid `dead-lock` and `starvation`.

thanks!

Comment: Use a 'critical section' to lock all four used nodes at once, or none at all and wait. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19316257/3080094

Comment: @vanOekel but that way I won't acquire starvation-free. I can wait forever like that. If I got a, b, c which a and c are faster then b that means that maybe a and c will always get to lock before b does.

Comment: @vanOekel Use of a single critical section for all threads could also introduce nearly as much contention as locking the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general answer, permitting the most concurrency, is to lock all of the four nodes involved in the reordering.  After they are all locked, check that the ordering hasn't changed - perhaps aborting and retrying if it has - then do the reordering, then release the locks in reverse order.

The tricky part is that, to avoid deadlock, the nodes have to be locked in order according to some fixed order.  Unfortunately, ordering them by position in the list won't work, since that ordering can change.  The nodes' hashCode and identityHashCode aren't guaranteed to work, since there can be collisions.  You'll need to provide some ordering of your own, for example by giving each node a unique permanent ID on construction, which can then be used for the locking order.

Comment: Javadoc of `Object#hashCode` mentioned: As much as is reasonably practical, **the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects**.  It is not a guarantee though :P

Comment: Yes.  Ever since 64 bit Java became available, hash collisions became largely inevitable since hash codes are only 32 bit.  And counting on anything that's explicitly not guaranteed is a bad idea in concurrent programming; in this case, you'd likely get unexplained lockups every few months in production.